# Firebase Environment configuration is not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

The Firebase environment variables seem to be undefined even though I did everything according to docs.

I set my firebase environment according to docs like this:

```
firebase functions:config:set mailerlite.key='12345' mailerlite.groupid='id123'
```

By typing this CLI in my terminal

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

I retrieve it

```
{
  "mailerlite": {
    "key": "12345",
    "id": "id123"
  }
}
```

So far so good. BUT I cannot access it from my express.js. Here is my functions/index.js:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const sensitive = require('./sensitive.js');
var cors = require('cors');


const app = express();


var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:8081',
    'https://myapp.com'];
app.use(cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        // allow requests with no origin 
        // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
        if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
            var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
                'allow access from the specified Origin.';
            return callback(new Error(msg), false);
        }
        return callback(null, true);
    }
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const port = 3000
app.post('/subscribe', (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('key', functions.config().mailerlite.key);
    console.log('stringify', JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log('req.body: ', req.body);
    //console.log('req.body.email', req.body.email);

    (async function () {
        try {
            const mailerLiteResponse = await fetch('https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/groups/' + sensitive.groupId + '/subscribers', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'Cors',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'X-MailerLite-ApiKey': functions.config().mailerlite.key,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(req.body)

            });



            const responseJson = await mailerLiteResponse.json();

            res.status(mailerLiteResponse.status).send(mailerLiteResponse.body);

            console.log('mailer response: ', responseJson);
            console.log('key2', functions.config().mailerlite.key);
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
    })();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Once I run the server this is the response I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at /Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/index.js:44:53
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/Users/tomas/code/ambee2_track_progress_server/functions/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log('key', functions.config())` to see if it returns anything at all?

Comment: this is the output of `console.log('key', functions.config())`:  `key {}` So, it appears firebase cli didn't assign the config keys correctly, however I can retrieve them via `firebase functions:config:get`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here that's bigger that just functions config.

Firstly, it's not at all possible to listen on a port in Cloud Functions.  This won't work at all when deployed:

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Cloud Functions will arrange to listen for you, and invoke your API endpoints when a request is incoming.  You just export your express app, and it will wire that up to a managed socket.

Before doing anything with environment config, I suggest getting your express app to work with a simple example, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps), then add config to it later.

Comment: thanks for your answer Doug. Just want to add to the knowledge base that the server works as it should (even with  app.listen(port,...) it's only the environment config that is causing issues on the outside.

Comment: It might work when testing locally, but it will not work when deployed.  What you're doing is simply not supported by Cloud Functions.

Comment: As surprising as it may sound to you, it is working also when deployed. I just tested it.